# Cannot code an decryption for my encryption

Tags: python, cryptography

I had to make this encryption for a Python problem.

```
def encrypt(n,string):
    #get length of string
    length = len(string)

    #traverse string and move text to newStringList
    newStringList = []
    for i in range(0,length,n):
        newStringList.append(string[i:i+n])
    #endfor

    #add to orderedList
    o = len(newStringList)
    orderedList = []

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(o):
            if j<len(newStringList) and i<len(newStringList[j]):
                orderedList.append(newStringList[j][i])
        #endfor
    #endfor

    #join list into string
    encrypted = "".join(orderedList)
    print(encrypted)
#end def
```

This works so that the string will be made into a table of n columns. The encrypted string is then made by reading down the columns one by one.  My problem involves the decryption of this.

If I use the exact same code to decrypt, it works only if `len(string)%n == 0`. For example if I entered `decrypt(3,"147258369")` it prints out `123456789` but if I enter `decrypt(3,"1470258369")` it should print out `1234567890` but instead it prints `1089423756`.  I've spent ages trying to decrypt and I can't get it right, can I have some help please.
**EDIT**
I was unfortunately testing with a number that worked more by coincidence than by method, it doesn't always work when `len(string)%n == 0`. Could anyone offer an alternative solution. My encryption code works as I want it but I cannot figure out how to code a successful decryption.
**Addition**
A solution using only basic tests and loops would be much appreciated, similar to my encryption.

Comment: `decrypt(3,"1470258369") == 1089423756`  ... however I believe `decrypt(4,"1470258369") == 1234567890 `  (without testing it)

Comment: @JoranBeasley `decrypt(4,"1470258369")` returns `1264597803` sorry

Comment: oh you are right ... my bad

Comment: it also fails when len(s) % n == 0 `(2,"1234567890")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oh damn it, I'll edit my question now. I was unfortunately testing my program with one of the few combos that actually worked. Thanks for that, I should have tested more thoroughly

Comment: There are easier ways   encrypt/decrypt, your problem lies in the fact you don't rotate the numbers, using modulo to encrypt/decrypt may be easier. You should not get an indexerror if your logic was correct

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know if this is any better but I managed to remove the indexError.

Comment: is there any particular criteria you have to follow?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No not really, but I'd rather it didn't have any shortcuts in it as I'm only a beginner and I want to learn proper solution that I understand.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using ord:

```
def encrypt(n, string):
    return "".join(chr(ord(ch) + n * n) for ch in string)


def decrypt(n, string):
    return "".join(chr(ord(ch) - n * n) for ch in string)

In [14]: e = encrypt(3, "123456789")

In [15]: e
Out[15]: ':;<=>?@AB'

In [16]: decrypt(3, e)
Out[16]: '123456789'
```

To encrypt we simply change the characters using ord adding the `ord` of each char + n * n then to decrypt we simply - n * n.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works, though it doesn't give you a perfectly involutive encryption function:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def encrypt_chunker(it, n):
    for i in range(0, len(it), n):
        yield it[i:i+n]

def decrypt_chunker(it, n, overflow):
    i = 0
    base_width = len(it) // n
    while i < len(it):
        if overflow:
            width = base_width + 1
            overflow -= 1
        else:
            width = base_width
        yield it[i:i+width]
        i += width

def crypt(string, n, mode):
    if mode == 'encrypt':
        chunks = encrypt_chunker(string, n)
    elif mode == 'decrypt':
        overflow = len(string) % n
        chunks = decrypt_chunker(string, n, overflow)
    thing = zip_longest(*chunks)
    crypted = ''.join(''.join(c for c in tup if c) for tup in thing)
    return crypted
```

Observe:

```
>>> crypt('1234567890', 3, 'encrypt')
'1470258369'
>>> crypt(_, 3, 'decrypt')
'1234567890'
>>> s = '1234567890'; n = 3; assert crypt(crypt(s, n, 'encrypt'), n, 'decrypt') == s # no AssertionError
```

`crypt(string, n, 'encrypt')` is the same as your `encrypt(n, string)` (verified on a large number of random strings and values of `n`). To get an involution, you have to do something like `crypt(crypt(string, n, 'encrypt'), n, 'decrypt')`.

I don't think it's possible to have a perfectly involutive encryption function like the one you described - you're throwing information away when you perform the encryption (specifically, the location of the "blanks" in your innermost loop). This is why you sort of have to add one bit of information - whether you're encrypting or decrypting. This allows you to determine the correct way to chunk the string.